# How to create the right certificate to elevate trust in Silverlight 5 application?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, elevated-privileges, full-trust

I read about using P/Invoke through Silverlight 5 and tried and it works.
But it only works in a trusted environment. This means that applications downloaded from
the remote website is not run in an elevated trust.

I digitally signed my application with self signed test certificate but it is stuck only to my computer. I would like to be able to create a certificate with public key that can be used to elevate trust to my application downloaded from internet site and to be working on any PC.

It is good to me if the user needs to install the certificate manually.

It will be better to make this procedure automatic but let's resolve problems step by step.

Answer (score 1):

*Mr. Goodcat* has written a comprehensive blog post on how to set up certificates for Silverlight 5 in-browser trusted applications, [here](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications.aspx).

Note that due to the certificate requirement, Silverlight in-browser elevated trust applications are only realistically deployed in an intranet. Depending on what your application is intended for, an alternative option could perhaps be to require that the application is run out-of-browser in order to make use of the elevated-trust functionality.

Comment: This is misleading. You *should* get certificates for OOB too, if you don't want big ugly warning signs.

Comment: Point taken. Removed corresponding sentence from the answer.